# How can I shorten a lot of if statements? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x

How can I shorten all of the `if` statements in the `for` loop? I am developing this for a college project. I cannot think of a way.

Basically the thing it should do is that if a certain location on a board does not equal a rock, then set it as a plant. The locations are a circle around the plant. Example:

N N N
N P N
N N N

```
if RainFall == 2:
    print("This summer has been a perfect summer, the plants have multiplied.")
    for Row in range(FIELDLENGTH):
        for Column in range(FIELDWIDTH):
            if Field[Row][Column] == PLANT:
                if Field[Row + 1][Column] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row + 1][Column] = GOODSUMMER
                if Field[Row - 1][Column] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row - 1][Column] = GOODSUMMER
                if Field[Row + 1][Column + 1] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row + 1][Column + 1] = GOODSUMMER
                if Field[Row - 1][Column - 1] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row - 1][Column - 1] = GOODSUMMER
                if Field[Row][Column + 1] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row][Column + 1] = GOODSUMMER
                if Field[Row][Column - 1] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row][Column - 1] = GOODSUMMER
                if Field[Row + 1][Column + 1] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row + 1][Column - 1] = GOODSUMMER
                if Field[Row - 1][Column + 1] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row - 1][Column + 1] = GOODSUMMER
                break
```

Comment: lot of ways. But you want to generalize it in a way that will help you develop it later. One idea is to have a method to evaluate a square, and call it once for all the squares around it. Stuff like this kind of begs for object oriented programming.

Comment: I am not a Python person, but in OOP, there is Command Pattern  for such situations. After digging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1494532/5058677

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, put your index permutations in a list and iterate over that. You can either define the list explicitely (more readable for beginners, but more error prone) or generate it with a comprehension. Explicit version first:

```
coord_shift = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (1, 1), (-1, -1), (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, -1), (-1, 1)]
for Row in range(FIELDLENGTH):
    for Column in range(FIELDWIDTH):
        if Field[Row][Column] == PLANT:
            for i, j in coord_shift:
                if Field[Row + i][Column + j] != ROCKS:
                    Field[Row + i][Column + j] = GOODSUMMER
```

Some additional notes:

Recommended Python style is to use lowercase variable names for regular variables, uppercase guys are more meant for classes.

You don't need break.

The above catches your small mistake for `Field[Row +1][Column -1]`.

The adventurous version I promised is:

```
coord_shift = [(i, j) for i in range(-1, 2) for j in range (-1, 2)]
coord_shift.drop((0, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can only guess about the rest of your code, so included down below is a full implementation for testing purposes. To see your reworked code, check out the `multiply_plants` function. Instead of a having many `if` statements, it uses loops to check the area around a cell. You may also notice that is correctly checks for the bounds of each list so that `IndexError` exceptions do not occur.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import random


FIELD_ROWS = 10
FIELD_COLUMNS = 10
EMPTY = ' '
PLANT = 'P'
ROCKS = 'R'
NEW_PLANT = 'N'


def main():
    field = create_field()
    show_field(field)
    multiply_plants(field, 2)
    replace_cells(field, NEW_PLANT, PLANT)
    show_field(field)


def create_field():
    field = []
    for _ in range(FIELD_ROWS):
        row = []
        for _ in range(FIELD_COLUMNS):
            row.append(random.choice([EMPTY] * 3 + [ROCKS] * 2 + [PLANT] * 1))
        field.append(row)
    return field


def show_field(field):
    width = max(map(len, field)) * 2 + 1
    print(f'/{"-" * width}\\')
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(['|'] + row + ['|']) for row in field))
    print(f'\\{"-" * width}/')


def multiply_plants(field, rainfall):
    # If there was enough rain, cause the plants to spread.
    if rainfall > 1:
        print('This summer has been a perfect summer;')
        print('the plants have multiplied!')
        # Find each space that already has a plant in it.
        for y, row in enumerate(field):
            for x, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell == PLANT:
                    # Introduce a Y-axis offset to search up & down.
                    for y_offset in range(-1, 2):
                        y_index = y_offset + y
                        if 0 <= y_index < len(field):
                            # Introduce a X-axis offset to search left & right.
                            for x_offset in range(-1, 2):
                                if y_offset or x_offset:    # Skip zero offset.
                                    x_index = x_offset + x
                                    if 0 <= x_index < len(field[y_index]):
                                        # Spread plant to non-rock areas.
                                        if field[y_index][x_index] != ROCKS:
                                            field[y_index][x_index] = NEW_PLANT


def replace_cells(field, old, new):
    for y, row in enumerate(field):
        for x, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == old:
                field[y][x] = new


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```